# Bash Script don't make folders and tries to move it self

Tags: bash

I´m writing a bash script that should sort photos by parts of they´re names to folders.
The problem it gives me a lot of errors and I can't find the mistake. Even ShellCheck don't found something so If u guys can help me that would be great.

My Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

Total=$(ls -1 | wc -l)
echo "$Total"
Count=1

while [[ $Count < $Total ]]
do
    NameOut=$(ls -1 | grep -o '[^-]*,[^-]*' | sed -n "$Count"p)
    echo "$NameOut"
    Filename=$(ls -1 | sed -n "$Count"p)
    echo "$Filename"
    if [ -d "$NameOut" ]; then
        mv "$Filename" "$NameOut"/
        Count=$((Count + 1))
    else
        mkdir "$NameOut"
        mv "$Filename" "$NameOut"/
        Count=$((Count + 1))
    fi
done
```

The script tries for some reason to move the script itself and it don't make the folders - and can't move the files because there are no folders to move them in to.
The directory it self contains files that are looking like this:

```
ls -1

REZ-Name,Surname-02-12-1996.jpg
BLEACH-Name,Surname-04-08-2008.jpg
```

Comment: I rolled your edits back because the **fundamentally** changed the question you were asking and that's not how this site works. If the solution given solved the problem you asked then you accept it and ask a new question for the new problems.

Answer (score 1):

shellcheck does identify a couple of issues with this script.

This script is also hugely inefficient as it repeatedly loops over the contents of the file when it doesn't need to do that.

An array of filenames would be a **much** better way to do this task.

That being said none of that has anything to do with the error you listed.

The problem with your script is the `print` lines.

What are you expecting them to be doing?

The `echo` lines are printing out your variable values already. Did you mean `printf '%s\n' "$var"` there? (Which would just duplicate the `echo` lines output?)

`print` is a different command entirely and is trying to figure out how to print the argument you gave it (as in to a printer, etc.).

---

Untested but something like this will probably do what you want. The remaining use of `grep` can almost certainly be replaced also but without seeing representative input and output this was less likely to have deviated from the original intention.

```
#!/bin/bash

files=(*)
total=${#files[@]}
echo "$total"

count=1
while (( count < total )); do
    filename=${files[count - 1]}
    echo "$filename"
    nameout=$(echo "$filename" | grep -o '[^ ]*,[^ ]*')
    mkdir -p "$nameout"
    mv "$filename" "$nameout/"
    count=$((count + 1))
done
```

Comment: There just for debugging so I know what is stored in the variables

Comment: The `echo` lines are doing that for you. The `print` lines are incorrect. Did you mean `printf` perhaps?

Comment: Also, @Nroh 's use of ` >> Names.txt` is well known shell anti-pattern, that is building up a bigger and bigger file each time s/he runs the script to test it. Note that `print` works like `printf` and `echo` in `ksh`, but does NOT work for debugging purposes in `bash` (it tries to send a file to a printer). Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter Your solution didn't worked completely but I updated the post above with the code that is working now. Thank u.